# Display Black&White MapKit

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I'm working on an app with a MapKit map, which I want to display as **Black&White**, rather than the default color scheme.

How do I do that?

Is there a method I can set the color scheme with?
Are there specific constants I can set for the color scheme?
Is there a combination of masking the MapKit view with some image that applies an effect of Black&White?

Thanks,
Nur

Comment: I would suggest you http://cloudmade.com/ they have customized maps and color schemes

Answer (score 1):

You can use [route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) instead of UIMapView and select the desired mapsource that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to change the colour of the map in `MKMapView`. The only thing you can change really is the [`mapType` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/mapType) which defines if it's a standard map, satellite or hybrid.

I doubt you'd be able to easily do anything with an overlay to make it B&W either. It might even be a violation of the terms of using the Google maps to do that anyway - I'm not sure on that, but it's possible it is.

So if you really need it B&W then I suggest using something other than the standard `MKMapView`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on some of the answers:

You cannot set MapKit to black and white. It violates the terms of use.

Your best bet is you use [route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) with an offline tileSource. Google TileMill. They allow you to create your own maps from shape files which you can download off different sites. You then use route-me to display the maps you created.